# Cable getting stuck - pyhsics

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I've been trying to create an animation in which a high-poly object is lowered from a building using a pulley. I'm still a beginner when it comes to physical simulations. The pulley cable is made of metal, but I assumed it starts from a point (I'll animate the texture), and I've applied a cloth simulation, making it quite taut to give it an aluminum-like appearance. My goal is to simulate the cable momentarily getting stuck, as if the object starts swaying from side to side for a moment before stabilizing. How do you suggest I proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first thought: simulations are expensive and can be tedious with trial and error adjusting the dozens of parameters.

What about using a vertex group Shape Key with proportional editing around the area you want to bend:

[image]

And then you would animate the keyframe where it would start to bend and eventually straighten again.   [image]

Here is an example file with animation [image]